# Order of adjectives for hair

Tags: adjective-order

I know the order of adjectives,but I don’t know which sentence is correct?

1. She has curly shoulder-length red hair.
2. She has shoulder-length curly red hair.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this question is hard? and why it is important? Have you, for example, searched for examples of these phrases?

Comment: Since no-one else has done it, here are the hits from Google Books...  [curly shoulder-length red](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22curly+shoulder-length+red%22):179, [curly red shoulder-length](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22curly+red+shoulder-length%22):9, [red curly shoulder-length](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22red+curly+shoulder-length%22):6, [red shoulder-length curly](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22red+shoulder-length+curly%22):50, [shoulder-length red curly](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shoulder-length+red+curly%22):7,...

Comment: [...shoulder-length curly red](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shoulder-length+curly+red%22):123. Some sequences are clearly more likely than others, but it's a fairly pointless question, imho.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that most native English speakers would choose your first option.

But if you were engaged in a conversation with someone about this person's hair in which the other speaker said:

> I was told that she had short, curly red hair.

You might well reply:

> No, she has shoulder-length, curly red hair.

because it's the length of her hair that's of specific interest.

Comment: Quite. There's at least a *tendency* to put the contextually most important adjective first (though we sometimes specifically choose to put the more important one ***last*** anyway, plus it might make a difference if you were going to place heavy stress on one of them). But if Google Books is to be believed, ***shoulder-length curly red*** runs OP's first version a close second.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that some lists of adjectives go into more detail than others.  For example, in the list provided by [Cambridge English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order), *size* comes before *shape*

> She had **shoulder-length**, curly, red hair

However, this is only one convention, and I don't think it would be odd to write it the other way around.  Plus, as Ronald Sole already mentioned, English speakers tend to put the most *contextually important* adjectives first.

Answer (score 0):

Of your three adjectives, shoulder-length (size) comes earliest in the order list, then curly (shape) and finally red (colour), so thus: shoulder-length curly red hair.